# Hive Query on selecting describe statement as select

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hue

I am trying to do a select for all attributes as columnname , i was wondering if this is possible in hive,
I have found out that within sql , we are able to extract its attributes as select statement.

The query i have tried is as shown below  :
In my hive ,

- DB im using is : gfr_staging
- Table : spt_myr

  ```
   SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS `Field`, COLUMN_TYPE AS `Type`
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS  
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'gfr_standard' AND TABLE_NAME = 'spt_myr';
  ```

But it returns me error. i was wondering if this is possible in hive

Comment: Hive does not support metastore queries. If you can connect directly to it's metastore (usually MySQL or Postgres) then you can query in it. But not in Hive.

Comment: Yes to @leftjoin, You can connect directly to the merastore DB and get the info. Also you can write a program to collect all info and store in hive to query if needed.

Comment: Some examples of parsing DESCRIBE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45053915/2700344, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58012261/2700344, parsing show partitions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398209/2700344